# Capture Aliasing in Subroutine

Tags: fortran

Is there a way to check whether aliasing occurs in a Fortran subroutine, or at least to tell the compiler to issue a warning?

Consider this (rather simplistic) example:

```
module alias
contains
  subroutine myAdd(a, b, c)
    integer,intent(in)    :: a, b
    integer,intent(inout) :: c

    c = 0
    c = a + b
  end subroutine
end module

program test
  use alias
  integer :: a, b

  a = 1 ; b = 2
  call myAdd(a, b, b)
  print *, b, 'is not 3'
end program
```

Here, the result is set to zero in the subroutine. If the same variable is given as input and output, the result is (obviously) wrong. Is there a way to capture this kind of aliasing at run-time or at compile-time?

Comment: Is this equivalent to the `C#` statement `myAdd(ref int a, ref int b, out int c) { }` and called with `myAdd(ref a, ref b, out b);`? I know `C#` wouldn't complain about this, and it produces unintended results. I don't think `fortran` is going to be any smarter in this respect.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with C#, but to me this looks similar...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, gfortran will detect some aliasing with the compiler option `-Waliasing`, however, the arguments must have intents `in` and `out`.   It won't work with your example because you have declared argument `c` as `intent(inout)`.   In this example you can simply change the intent to `out` since the input value of `c` is not used.  They try the compiler option!   gfortran outputs:

```
alias.f90:17.16:

  call myAdd(a, b, b)
                1
Warning: Same actual argument associated with INTENT(IN) argument 'b' and INTENT(OUT) argument 'c' at (1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I could easily change the routines s.t. `c` is `intent(out)`, and now I have a tool to check for aliasing!

Comment: Another +1, if I could! This helped me find additional bugs in my code ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of options in g95 or gfortran to detect the aliasing error at compile or run time. The programmer is responsible for avoiding such an error. You can pass the intent(in) arguments as expressions to ensure that they are not changed within the subroutine, as shown below.

```
module alias
contains
  subroutine myAdd(a, b, c)
    integer,intent(in)    :: a, b
    integer,intent(inout) :: c
    c = 0
    c = a + b
  end subroutine myadd
end module alias

program test
  use alias, only: myadd
  integer :: a, b
  a = 1 ; b = 2
  call myAdd((a),(b),b) ! parentheses around arguments a and b
  print*, b,"is 3"
  call myAdd(a, b, b)
  print*, b,"is not 3"
end program test
```

Comment: Hm, interesting - this has never occurred to me before! I wonder how that would work with derived types. My guess would be, that at least an assignment has to be defined... I'll play around a little, and report back ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your idea! I learned something new... I tested it for my actual code, but it made things *very* complicated. So I'll stick with M.S.B.'s solution!